# Different filters for 2d convolution

Tags: conv-neural-network, pytorch, convolution

I’m having an input of shape (B(atch), F(features), N(odes), T(timestamps)). Right now if I apply a 2d convolution with a kernel of shape (1,2) I will have a total of (F_out, F_in, 1,2) weights to learn which is alright. I want to extend this so that for each Node in the input I have it’s own filter with shape (1,2). Does any of you have any idea where should I start from? So far I looped through all N and apply the filter to its respective input. Unfortunately this approach is very slow.

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for "grouped convolution".
The doc for [`nn.Conv2d`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.html#conv2d) regarding the `groups` parameter:

> At `groups=2`, the operation becomes equivalent to having two conv layers **side by side**, each seeing half the input channels, and producing half the output channels, and both subsequently concatenated.

In your case, you want `groups=` number of nodes.

It's not that simple in your case, because you want to "merge" features and nodes, and to have only 1d grouped convolution over the "feature"+"node" dimension.
Moreover, you need to permute between "node"s and "feature"s in order to group the features according to nodes.

```py
b = 10;
inf = 8;
outf = 13;
n = 3;
t = 50;

x = torch.rand((b, inf, n, t))  # input tensor
gconv = nn.Conv1d(inf, outf, kernel_size=(2), groups=n) #grouped conv

x_ready = x.permute(0, 2, 1, 3).view(b, inf*n, t)  
y_grouped = gconv(x_ready)
# "fix" y
y = y_grouped.view(n, n, outf, t).permute(0, 2, 1, 3)  # now y is b-outf-n-t
```

Comment: I don’t think that I quite understand your solution. let’s take a simple example, 2 nodes with 2 features each, 2 time stamps and a kernel of size 1x2 filled with ones. As you can see from the image the two timestamps are convolved into one, but there is no information going from node 1 to node 2 which is intended. Now I would like for each node to have it’s own filter, so features 1,2 are going to be multiplied with a filter and 2,4 with another, and same thing for the other channel but the results should still be summed together. Link: to the image https://ibb.co/gZBFH3m